# About proving an abelian group as a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

This question is the following.

> Consider the abelian group under addition of elements of the form $ar_0+br_1+cr_2$ where $a,b,c\in \mathbb Z$ and $r_0,r_1,r_2$ are variables.
>   1. Define a multiplication on this set that turns it into a ring with the property that $r_i*r_k=r_{i+k}$ where i,k works like elements of $\mathbb Z_3$
>   
> 2. Show that this is a ring. 
> 3. Does unity exist? If so, find it.

I defined the multiplication to be the following.

> For $A,B \in \{ar_0+br_1+cr_2|a,b,c \in \mathbb Z\}$, $A=a_0r_0+a_1r_1+a_2r_2$ and $B=b_0r_0+b_1r_1+b_2r_2$.
>   $A*B=(a_0b_0+a_1b_2+a_2b_1)r_0+(a_0b_1+a_1b_0+a_2b_2)r_1+(a_0b_2+a_2b_0+a_1b_1)r_2$

Is this the right multiplication that the question asks to me?

And for question 2, Since addition is given as abelian group, I need to show that the multiplication I've defined is associative and the distribution law holds. Right?

Thank you.

Comment: This looks right to me, for example: If $A=r_1$ and $B=r_2$ then $A*B = r_0$ so your multiplication works.

Comment: For the second question, you are right about what you need to show!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_ring ($R=\mathbb{Z}$, $G=C_3$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is right multiplication. In fact, this ring is isomorphic to the integer ring of the group $\mathbb{Z}_3$.

Comment: And about the unity, does it exist? Because you wrote that the ring is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_3$, I thought there would be unity in this ring also.

Comment: Of course, the unity is $1\cdot r_0$.